# Where do I run the Kahlan php command at?

Tags: php

I am new to php static analyzers and have installed [Kahlan](https://github.com/phan/phan/wiki/Getting-Started) via composer on one of my projects as the document instructed.

The document further says, With the Phan dependency installed, you can do analysis by running the following (once you create a configuration file).

> **./vendor/bin/phan**

Now, where do Kahlan wants me to run the above command at?

I went to the window command prompt and enter the ./vendor/bin/phan and the cmd prompt says

*'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are you linking is a PHP script. To be able to run it in windows console, you have to install PHP language interpreter first. Get it on www.php.net